# How to paste the text from clipboard into textbox and assert in testcafe?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation, testcafe

I have a text field in a table and I want to copy the contents of the clipboard to textfield

As paste option is not available in testcafe, so tried the below:

```
const execPaste = ClientFunction(() => document.execCommand("paste"));
t..click(Selector(".table > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(3)"))
    .typeText(
      Selector(".table > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(3)"),
      JSON.stringify(execPaste())
    );
console.log(JSON.stringify(execPaste()));
```

and in the console log I see "{"_then":[],"_taskPromise":null}" and not the value which is copied from the clipboard

Please help

Answer (score 2):

The [`ClientFunction`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/#creating-client-functions) returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so to get the `ClientFunction` value, you need to [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) this promise:

```js
JSON.stringify(await execPaste())
```

To paste a value from the clipboard, you can focus the element where you are going to paste the value and then call the `document.execCommand("paste")` method. If I understand your code correctly, the first `click` is supposed to focus the target element.
Please try to change your code example in the following way:

```js
    const execPaste = ClientFunction(() => document.execCommand("paste"));

    await t.click(Selector(".table > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(3)"));
    await execPaste();
```

Comment: Yes click is gaining focus

Comment: Tried this but console.log("execpaste" + (await execPaste())); returns false and doesnot copy the contents of the cllipboard to the text field. Manually I can the see the text content when I paste into the same textfield

Comment: The document.exeCommand function returns false if the command is unsupported or disabled: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand). Make sure that you are running this command in an appropriate place and at a proper time. Debug your test case to see what's going on: [https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/debugging.html](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/debugging.html).